# Packet time change in Scapy

Tags: scapy

I'm generating a pcap from hex strings gathered from network elements that aren't able to generate it by themselves and this is my last piece of puzzle:

How can I change .time of a packet with the epoch value I want?

Unfortunately I didn't find anything for that until now.